# Wildlfy module.xml Configuration for one java class

Tags: java, maven-3, jboss-modules

I am testing an java application and getting this error:

```
org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.NamingIOException: Failed to rebind [Root exception is java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.brockhaus.userMgmt.control.process.SomeProcess from [Module "org.jboss.remote-naming:main" from local module loader @ed17bee (finder: local module finder @2a33fae0 (roots: C:\Program Files\jboss\wildfly\modules,C:\Program Files\jboss\wildfly\modules\system\layers\base))]]
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.brockhaus.userMgmt.control.process.SomeProcess from [Module "org.jboss.remote-naming:main" from local module loader @ed17bee (finder: local module finder @2a33fae0 (roots: C:\Program Files\jboss\wildfly\modules,C:\Program Files\jboss\wildfly\modules\system\layers\base))]
```

So my purpose is modifying the module.xml file of

C:\Program Files\jboss\wildfly\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\remote-naming\main

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.jboss.remote-naming">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="jboss-remote-naming-2.0.4.Final.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.ejb-client" optional="true"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.remoting"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.marshalling"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.marshalling.river"/>
        <module name="de.brockhaus.userMgmt.control.process"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

But this also gives errors. I would like to know how to change this above xml file in order to achieve the things working right.

Comment: What is de.brockhaus.userMgmt.control.process? Your own library? And why you add that to existing jboss module?

Comment: de.brockhaus.userMgmt.control.process is the package where the class SomeProcess is. I have added it to jboss module org.jboss.remote-naming because of the error message showed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.brockhaus.userMgmt.control.process.SomeProcess from [Module "org.jboss.remote-naming:main"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modify jboss system modules
you can create your own modules

create a directory /modules/com/xyz/some/main
with files

1. module.xml
2. some-class.jar

some-class.jar

module.xml

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.xyx.some">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="some-class.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.jboss.remote-naming"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

and add it as part of global module configuration

open file /standalone/configuration/standalone-full.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:4.0">
            <global-modules>
                <module name="com.microfocus.itom.nom.common" slot="main"/>
            </global-modules>
```